# WPF Separator Background Color Stays Gray

Tags: c#, wpf, separator

I have a WPF menu with a separator that I'd like to be black and 1 pixel wide. However, the separator seems to have a built-in 30 pixel wide buffer space that I can't change the color on. In the example below I set my separator to 50 pixels wide--as you can see the first 30 pixels don't reflect the proper background color. Very annoying! What am I missing?

[image]

Here's the XAML:

```
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="45" Height="62" Name="Menu">
            <MenuItem Header="_Home" Name="HomeMenuItem" Click="HomeMenuItem_Click" Padding="10,0,10,0"></MenuItem>
            <Separator Width="50" Background="Black" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0"></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="_Print" Name="PrintMenuItem" Click="PrintMenuItem_Click" Padding="10,0,10,0"></MenuItem>
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the ControlTemplate for the menu automatically includes margin for the Separator. Thanks to [Rowbear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063835/rowbear) I now understand that the ControlTemplate overrides styles. The solution then was to add a custom template to the Application.Resources. (I'm sure it would have worked just fine to do it in Windows.Resources, etc.)

```
    <Style x:Key="SeparatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Border Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="#40000000"></Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then in the main XAML window references the custom ControlTemplate like this:

```
<Separator Width="1" Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"></Separator>
```